# Puxar dados do SQL Server usando PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Olá pessoal usando o código PHP abaixo consigo inserir linhas na minha tabela do SQL Server:

```
sqlsrv_query( $conn, "INSERT INTO usuarios (login, senha) VALUES ('new', 'mano')");
```

Porem, eu gostaria de retornar algum valor e jogar num texto.
Tentei o comando abaixo mas não está aparecendo o login correspondende daquele numero.

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, "SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE numero = 8");
```

Aparece: **O nome é: Resource id #3**

Sendo que no banco de dados, o login de numero 8 é Joao.

Entao deveria aparecer: **O nome é: Joao**

Comment: O campo numero é de inteiros? Se não, coloque o 8 dentro de aspas simples

Comment: Sim, ele é como se fosse o ID de uma conta

Comment: Não se percebe a dúvida que estás a ter. Um login e senha mal explícitos. Na query coloca tudo que queres "puxar" do SQL

Comment: Eu consigo inserir, mas não consegui selecioar

Answer (score 0):

Segue este exemplo, que te vai ajudar a resolver o teu problema, tens apenas de trocar o nome do servidor e da instancia de sql server, bem como o utilizador e a password de acesso ao servidor.

De qualquer das formas estas a guardar informação sem estar cifrada, e um grave problema de segurança, mas isto foi um à parte.

```
<?php
$serverName = "servidor\instancia";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"bancodedados", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE numero = 8";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
      echo $row[0] . "<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>
```